# A time counter in c++

Tags: c++

I want to programme a code in C++ that makes a time-counting at the same time while we are waiting the user to  enter for example the integer result we want to see.For instance we want user to enter two integers and select one of the four operations,then write down the result.Meanwhile the clock or the counting machine starts to count the seconds until the user write down the result.
Is it possible to do in C++,if it's not how can I do this?
Thanks...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 10):

C++11/14 give you even more efficient ways than the old `#include<ctime> headers of C` to measure `time duration` using certain classes like `steady_clock`, `high_resolution_clock`, etc defined in the header `#include<chrono>`. The following code does your job very efficiently:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   chrono::steady_clock sc;   // create an object of `steady_clock` class
   auto start = sc.now();     // start timer

   // do stuff....

   auto end = sc.now();       // end timer (starting & ending is done by measuring the time at the moment the process started & ended respectively)
   auto time_span = static_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(end - start);   // measure time span between start & end
   cout<<"Operation took: "<<time_span.count()<<" seconds !!!";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: each time it is returning little bit different time. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way it to use `std::clock_t`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::clock_t start;
    double duration;

    start = std::clock(); // get current time

    // Do your stuff here

    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    std::cout << "Operation took "<< duration << "seconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There are many ways to do that actually. This one is portable and does not need any extra library to be available. As long as you need second precision, it will be OK.