# C++ inaccurate timer

Tags: c++, asynchronous, timer, c++-chrono

```
#include <iostream>
#include "current_time.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>    
using namespace std;
current_time mytimer;

void timer()
{
    while(true)
    {
        mytimer.operator++(); //incerements seconds 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    void(*foo)(void);
    foo = &timer;
    auto future = async(foo);
    while (1)
    {       
        Sleep(50);
        system("cls");
        mytimer.disp_time();
    }
}
```

My background timer isn't accurate. After waiting some time I noticed that it was slowly getting more and more late. I know it's because mytimer.operation++() takes some time to run. I was looking for a fix, but I cant't find any. I am currently using VS15.

Comment: Have you considered synchronizing it with the system clock instead of just counting seconds?

Comment: What's `current_time` actually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A time counter in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065568/a-time-counter-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sleep_for` really means something like `sleep_for_at_least`. On a realtime OS you might be able to depend on its waking up exactly when asked, but on a conventional OS, it can sleep for some arbitrary amount of time longer than specified.

If you need long-term synchronization with a wall clock, you usually want to compute when the next wake-up should take place mathematically (i.e., multiply the intended duration by the number of sleeps so far to get the ideal wakeup time), and `sleep_until` that time. This way each single wakeup can be somewhat late, but the error doesn't accumulate from one to the next. You can do this by computing the difference between the wakeup time and the current time, then us `sleep_for` that difference, but this usually sacrifices a little accuracy (the time taken by everything subsequent to obtaining the current time) and extra work, since you still have the compute the next wakeup time.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected. A sleep is a sleep for *at least* that amount of time, not a precise scheduler to "do a thing at a specific time".

You're not considering the amount of time it takes to actually run your code each second, or to wake from sleep, or to start sleeping again .. not to mention all the other things your computer is doing in the meantime. Some drift is normal.

Instead of sleeping for 1 second, sleep for a certain number of microseconds (990,000 maybe?) based upon how much real time has elapsed since your last "iteration". The next wakeup may again be slightly late, but at least that lateness won't be cumulative, because your subsequent "sleep" argument will be slightly shorter to compensate.

That's the best naive scheduler you'll get.

Comment: The problem is that time of 1 iteration isn't always constant.

Comment: @WalterWhite: So? You have to measure the real time. As explained, it will be different each time _anyway_. That's the whole point!

Comment: @WalterWhite: Sorry you felt my answer didn't help you.

Comment: It did help me. I appreciate every answer.